# Redirecting domain with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm moving my site from the .com version to the .co.uk. The only issue is there are some admin facilities that I want to keep on the .com site. I've set up my .htaccess to redirect everything but requested files and directories that exist which works fine, except for the root of the site, I can't get that to redirect.

Here is my htaccess...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.site.co.uk/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ http://www.site.co.uk/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This regex `^(index\.php)?$` will match `index.php` OR empty string (landing page).